# Extracting month from day using linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am having a text file containing a list of date and time just like the sample below -

> posted_at"
> 2012-06-09 11:48:31"
> 2012-08-09 12:40:02"
> 2012-04-09 13:10:00"
> 2012-03-09 13:40:00"
> 2012-10-09 14:30:01"
> 2012-12-09 15:30:00"
> 2012-11-09 16:20:00"

I want to extract the month from each line.

P.S - grep should not be used at any point of the code
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Why not use grep?

Comment: The reason for closure is wrong. There are not multiple problems presented. It should be closed, but for reasons of lacking current attempts and the error messages associated therewith.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this reason is the closest (of the existing reasons to select), to what you say. Also consider this interpretation: When someone provides efforts and where the problem is (note: the problem is not the whole task, but the point of misunderstanding using a specific tool for this task) then the question is focused on this point.

Comment: @thanasisp it's not your fault. When StackExhanged "improved" the close menu, many of the reasons for closing that actually fit were replaced with selections that do not make a whole lot of sense anymore.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I agree that more reasons should be available for this menu, this discussion is for the meta-SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First select date pattern :

```
egrep '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' content_file
```

Second, extract the month :

```
awk -F '-' '{print $2}'
```

Third redirect to desired file :

```
>> desired_file
```

So mix of all this with | to final solution :

```
egrep '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ' content_file| awk -F '-' '{print $2}'>> desired_file
```

Voilà

Comment: But OP said: `P.S - grep should not be used at any point of the code Thanks in advance!`

Comment: Anyone using `grep` and `awk` within a pipeline is most likely doing it wrong ... just saying.

Comment: @tink could you be more explicit?

Comment: Sure ... `echo -e 'posted_at"\n2012-04-09 13:10:00"' | awk -F"-" '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/ {print $2}'`  ... why invoke two programs?

Comment: echo is a program too?